# Double Quotes in Excel and IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am confused with using double quotes and numbers. I know that if we need to refer to a text or a string in excel we need to enclose it with a double quotes in excel. But what about numbers ? Consider the following formula which works fine :

```
=IF(OR(E5="NY",E5="LA",E5="CA"),1000,0)
```

Also consider this formula which also works fine :

```
=IF(OR(E2="LA",E2="CA",E2="NY"),"1000","0")
```

What is the difference between the two formulas ? I think that the first one will generate 1000 and 0 as numbers , while the second one will generate the two numbers as text? However, when I perform any arithmetic operations on the generated numbers of the second formula ( which I assume that it generates numbers as text), the arithmetic operation works fine ! So what is the difference between enclosing numbers in quotes and without enclosing them in quotes specially in IF function ?

Comment: Not able to replicate your experiment's results. When summing the column that uses Formula 2, the value is 0. What is your arithmetic operation?

Comment: @Isolated its addition. I sum the column that contains the result of this if formula with another column that contains numbers in accounting format.

Comment: @Isolated so please can you explain generally what is the difference of including double quotes for numbers and without  enclosing them with quotes in IF formula ?

Comment: Well, for my version of Excel (MS 365 suite), the output is "text" when quotes are used. That would explain why I cannot replicate the behavior. But for your version, it seemingly retains the number format. Someone else may have a better idea, whether is an Excel Version thing, or some setting, or something else.

Comment: not researched, but it may have to do with using formulas like `COUNT()`, `COUNTA()` vs using operators (`+`,`-`,`*`,`&`)

Comment: I think @gns100 nailed it here. So, in my version this is the behavior: Using a `=SUM(C1:C3)` will not work, but doing `=C1+C2+C3` works. Like he/she mentioned, formula vs operator has unique behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, Excel treats the inputs you give in quotes as text when outputting them as results to the formulas.

If you use those results in a way that logically you clearly intend anything that looks like a number to be treated as such and there is no competing logic of "equal or higher validity," Excel WILL do so. So create six of these text number entries and use `SUM` on the cells and Excel will add them up nicely.

Use one of them as a lookup value though, so Excel has good reason to believe its text status supersedes the fact that it could be a number value, and the lookup will fail (well, if the value being sought in the lookup range is a number, not also text!).

So you see many uses in which the text value numbers are natively treated as numbers, not text, by Excel. And other times Excel seems to forget all about how it could do that. The above guide will get you in place generally for any given use, but of course, the programmers at MS might not have the thought that you "seriously man, I obviously meant those to be numbers for this use"...

Also, you might see "weirdness" of the sort that, say, using `SUMIF`, while it is happy to include the value in a numberlike way if in the "sum range" it might not treat that value as anything but text if it is in the "what to decide to sum range." So if in A1, `SUMIF(B1:B5, ">"&A1)` might see it value A1 as 0 since it contains text, and sum all of B1:B5, but `SUMIF(A1:A5, ">"&B1) might not see it summed if B1 has a value of, say, 30 because here it might see it as a value of 0 which is not >30.

The LOGIC would be the same as above, but seem pretty darned obtuse to the user having a nightmare figuring out what's happening.

By the way, the above is an example to illustrate the point. `SUMIF` might use it as a number in both cases, or neither... I have not experimented.

Also, the point of how it should be, and is, text if done as in the second formula is very correct. It's just that Excel is willing to bleed around the corners, so to speak. And daily life is how you find where the corners are and if it does. I've never seen even an attempt at a list of such things on anyone's help site.

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend further to Jeorje’s answer, rather than replace it.

As they pointed out, Excel’s interpreter makes some assumptions, and will convert a number stored as text into its number value if it’s obvious that’s what you want.  But that leads to some very unpredictable behavior so you have to be very careful about letting Excel decide.  Examples:

`=SUM(A1:A3)` returns `0` if A1:A13 contain `{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}`, meaning no conversion happened.

`=SUM(- -(A1:A3))` returns `2`, meaning a math operation (the “- -“) alerted Excel to our numeric intentions. Performing an obviously mathematical operation will usually force the conversion.

But oddly:

`=SUM(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)` returns `2` meaning conversion happened.
`=SUM({TRUE,TRUE,FALSE})` returns `0` meaning it didn’t.

If you are used to Excel getting this right, and then provide a logical array to SUM() for the first time, this could really trip you up.

The lesson learned:  Be very careful about assuming Excel will interpret your intentions correctly in each specific case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info !